# Remove '\[' and '\]' in Latex file with Vim vmapping

Tags: vim

I try to create an Visual mapping to remove `\[` and `\]` in Latex file.

e.g.

1. `\[ \textbf{my latex} \]`
2. highlight `\[ \textbf{my latex} \]` with `v`
3. run my visual mapping
4. `\textbf{my latex}`

I have came up with the following vmapping

```
autocmd BufEnter *.tex vmap  x[ :s/\%V\\\]\\|\\\[\%V// <CR>
```

But it only removes the `\[` instread of both `\[` and `\]`

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Obviously I can write a small function with `getline(".")` and use `substitute()` to solve it easily, but I want to have simple one line autocmd vmapping instead of Vim function.

Comment: Missing `g` flag on the `s///`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have `:set gdefault`, your `:substitute` command is missing the `/g` flag. Without it, only the *first* match in a line will be removed.

```
vmap  x[ :s/\%V\\\]\\|\\\[\%V//g <CR>
```

#### Further notes

- [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.
- As this is a buffer-local mapping (only for Tex files), you should add the `<buffer>` modifier.
- You can define that for certain filetypes by prepending `:autocmd Filetype {filetype} ...` (the `BufEnter` works as well, but you duplicate the filetype detection on the `*.tex` pattern), and put that into your `~/.vimrc`. But that gets unwieldy as you add mappings and other settings for various filetypes. Better put the commands into `~/.vim/ftplugin/{filetype}_mappings.vim` (`~/.vim/ftplugin/tex_mappings.vim` in your case). (This requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`.)

```
vnoremap <buffer>  x[ :s/\%V\\\]\\|\\\[\%V//g <CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternation is supposed to happen in a "group":

```
:s/foo\|bar//g        wrong
:s/\(foo\|bar\)//g    right
```

In your case:

```
:s/\%V\(\\\[\|\\\]\)//g
```

so…

```
augroup latex
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufEnter *.tex xnoremap x[ :s/\%V\(\\\[\|\\\]\)/<CR>
augroup END
```